# how to disable highcharts animation on panning but still using on load

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

on highchart 8.0.0 is possible zoom using the wheel
the problem is highcharts do an animation on scroll
I red the documentation but I only found disable all animations
is it posible do that?

```
$('#container').highcharts({
  chart: {
    panning: true
  },
  mapNavigation: {
    enabled: true,
    enableButtons: true
  },
  title: {
    text: 'USD to EUR exchange rate over time'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ?
      'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in' : 'Pinch the chart to zoom in'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Exchange rate'
    }
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  plotOptions: {
    area: {
      fillColor: {
        linearGradient: {
          x1: 0,
          y1: 0,
          x2: 0,
          y2: 1
        },
        stops: [
          [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
          [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
        ]
      },
      marker: {
        radius: 2
      },
      lineWidth: 1,
      states: {
        hover: {
          lineWidth: 1
        }
      },
      threshold: null
    }
  },

  series: [{
    type: 'area',
    name: 'USD to EUR',
    data: data
  }]
});
```

here is in jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/xm3692y8/2/

thanks in advance
best

Comment: You mean, there should not be animation for scroll or zoom-in and animation should be present while loading the graph.

Comment: yeah you are right

Answer (score 0):

I think that set chart.animation to false is a solution which you are looking for. It will disable animation for all chart updating, but the initial one will stay unchanged.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jLm8yrt6/

```
  chart: {
    panning: true,
    animation: false
  },
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.animation

Is that what you had in mind?